# Why aren't commas added when I use String.format method?

Tags: java, string, formatting

```
public class TestFormats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = String.format("%,d", 100000000);
        System.out.println(str1);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to separate digits of the number by commas using the method with the given parameters but, for some reason, commas aren't being added to the number, the only thing that's changed is that whitespaces emerged.

How can I make this work? Why isn't working, what's wrong?

Comment: It outputs `100,000,000` for me

Comment: Since I am German it uses dots. But I have the result I would exspect: `100.000.000`

Comment: @Lasnik hm, that's interesting. Maybe I'm getting this output, because I'm Russian

Comment: I don´t think so. But you can of cource always try it. The first argument of the String.format()  function can be a Locale Object. Modify it to something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your system Locale is not set to `ENGLISH`. Use `Locale.ENGLISH` as shown below:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%,d", 100000000);
        System.out.println(str1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
100,000,000
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because of your `Location`. Add the `Locale` object as an argument to the `String.format()` function

```java
    import java.util.Locale;
    
    public class TestFormats {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Uses commas 
            Locale localeEn = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").build();
            String str1 = String.format(localeEn, "%,d", 100_000_000);
            System.out.println(str1); //output: 100,000,000
            
            // Uses dots
            Locale localeDe = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("de").build();
            String str2 = String.format(localeDe, "%,d", 100_000_000);
            System.out.println(str2); //output: 100.000.000
            
            // Uses spaces
            Locale localeRu = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").build();
            String str3 = String.format(localeRu, "%,d", 100_000_000);
            System.out.println(str3); //output: 100 000 000
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me:

```
jshell>String str1 = String.format("%,d", 100000000);
...> 
str1 ==> "100,000,000"
```

Probably you're executing a different file (copy/pasted and buffer is showing the wrong file, happens to me all the time)

Comment: I'm executing the right file. I don't know what can cause the problem.

Comment: Hm interesting. Well what you're trying is correct, so it most be something else